# Java wrapper: overriding a method called in the super constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, wrapper

I want to wrap a class in Java but the problem is as follows:

```
public class A {

    public A() {
       doSomething();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
    }

}
```

Now when I try to wrap this class and delegate all methods to the wrapper

```
public class Wrapper extends A {

   private final A a;

   public Wrapper(A a) {
      super();
      this.a = a;
   }

   @Override
   public void doSomething() {
      this.a.doSomeThing();
   }


}
```

of course I get a NPE as 'a' is still null as it is set after the super()-call which calls the overriden doSomething() method. Is there any solution for this problem? The only thing that came to my mind was making a factory method and setting a static variable holding the reference to a but this seems ugly to me.

Comment: Never call overridable methods from a constructor!

Comment: @all: Ok I forgot to mention that A is a Java class [AbstractDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AbstractDocument.html) so it's not possible for me to introduce an init-method or change the constructor. And of course 'a' is one of many possible implemenations of A and not necessarily the same as Wrapper is extending from. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: Hmmm ... The class `javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument` has two constructors, that both do **not** call overridable methods. So, how does this match your question?

Comment: In the constructor protected AbstractDocument(Content data, AttributeContext context) a so called BidiElement is created which is a LeafElement and the LeafElement constructor calls the method createPosition(int offs)...

Comment: Ah. Now I see. Very bad design, I would say. You obviously are facing the problem, which is the problem, why overridable methods should never be called in constructors. There is no real way out.

Comment: Ok, that's bad. Nevertheless, thanks for your effort:) I accepted Ivaylo Slavov's answer as I think it provides the best explanation and solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way for this to be avoided is by exposing an `init` method (or any other name) from your base class (if you are in control of its logic). Then move the call from the constructor to the init method:

```
public class A {

    public A() {
    }

    public void init() {
        doSomething();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
    }
}
```

You should update your code to call the `init` method after making an instance of the class, which may be a bit of boilerplate:

```
A instance = new Wrapper();
instance.init();
```

instead of just

```
A instance = new Wrapper();
```

If you use Spring and DI, you can specify an `init-method` in the xml context, so Spring will call it for you when it resolves the dependency.

In case the `doSomething` method is **public**, and accepts no arguments, you can use it directly instead of the `init` method both in code and with Spring.

In general, use of overridable methods in a constructor is an anti-pattern, due to the problem you have encountered. There is no way to predict how a derived class will override the methods and if they rely on non-initialized resources, then you are in trouble.

Comment: I accept this answer as I think it's the best solution if someone faces this problem in his/her own code. Thx.

Comment: @zersaegen, Thanks, I am glad it helped you. Consider the patterns in the other answers as well. They are useful if `class A` comes from a 3rd party and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend changing the code so that doSomething is not called in the constructor.

Alternatively split A into an interface and implementation Wrapper implements the interface and does not inherit from A

```
public interface IA {

    public void doSomething() {
    }

}
public class A implements IA {

    public A() {
       doSomething();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
    }

}


public class Wrapper implements IA {

   private final IA a;

   public Wrapper(IA a) {
      this.a = a;
      doSomething();
   }

   @Override
   public void doSomething() {
      a.doSomeThing();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Wrapper this way. You do not need to hold A explicitly. The expression `super` is the same as your filed:

```
class Wrapper extends A {

    public Wrapper() {
    }

    @Override public void doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Or otherwise extract an interface and change your code like this:

```
class Wrapper implements AA {

    private final AA child;

    public Wrapper(AA child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

    @Override public void doSomething() {
        child.doSomething();
    }
}

class A implements AA {

    public A() {
       doSomething();
    }

    @Override public void doSomething() {}
}

interface AA {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

two small changes, young one you need

```
 public class Wrapper extends A {

       private final A a;

       public Wrapper(A a) {
          super();
          this.a = a;

        //this will execute method doSomething wrom Wrapper class after variable a is set
          doSomething(); 

       }

       @Override
       public void doSomething() {
    //this will prevent to call metod from superclass constructor, bit risky thou
         if (a!=null)       
          this.a.doSomething();
       }
    }
```

but overriding methods which are called in constructo is generally bad practice and smells terrible